# How to form a row complete Latin squares of order odd?

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

Hello dear mathematicians 
How to form a row complete latin square of order odd.
I found some answers for Latin squares of order even.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best known way of constructing row complete latin squares is via sequencable groups. A group is *sequencable* if its elements can be ordered, say as $g_0,g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}$, so that the map $g_i \mapsto g_i^{-1}g_{i+1}$ (for $0 \leq i \leq n-1$) is injective. We call such an ordering of the elements of a group a *directed terrace*.

Given a directed terrace $g_0,g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}$ the latin square $L$ defined by $L_{i,j} = g_i^{-1}g_{i+1}$ is row complete (for a proof of this fact see the introduction to M.A. Ollis' [dynamic survey](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS10/pdf) on sequencable groups).

But now we need to ask what we know about sequencable groups. Keedwell conjectured that every nonabelian group of order at least 10 is sequencable. The conjecture has been [confirmed](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01496.pdf) for all nonabelian groups of odd order at most 555.

Which leaves us with our final question: for which odd orders do we know there exists a nonabelian group? The answer to this question is nontrivial, and is given in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31553/finite-nonabelian-groups-of-odd-order) Mathoverflow question/answer.

Comment: To more directly answer the OP's question, the survey you linked gives a method to construct row complete Latin squares (RCLS) of any odd _composite_ order (except $9$) using finite fields. An order 9 RCLS is known. All that remains are prime orders, for which no RCLS's have been found.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Gosh, I should probably have skimmed that paper again before posting my answer. It seems as though a reference to HIgman's construction (Theorem 23 from Ollis' survey) would be the best answer here, while my answer is entirely tangential. Perhaps you should post it as another answer, which I will duly upvote?

Comment: I don’t plan on posting an answer, feel free to do so. Don’t feel bad about not reading the whole paper, one needn’t spend all their free time doing deep math research for recreational problems